# How do I properly connect Brevo and Contact Form 7 in Wordpress when it comes to SMS

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm having a problem properly integrating Brevo with CF7. The issue specifically occurs because of the SMS thing where if the number is not in the international format. (The Contact just completely fails to create).

I've searched the forum and I don't seem to be finding any answers, I just see a link to the mapping docs. Is there anyway at all to have CF7 validate numbers in the international format or am I able to edit the sendinbluephp file to match the attribute to the field Country & Phone Field Contact Form 7 creates and not the tel field from CF7?

CF7 Form:

```
<div class="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Name (required)
    [text* your-name placeholder "Your name"] </label>
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Company (required)
    [text* company-name placeholder "Your company name"] </label>   
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Email (required)
    [email* your-email placeholder "Your working email"] </label>       
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Phone (required)
[tel* your-sms "+1"]
</label>
<label> Phone - Country & Phone Field Contact Form 7 plug 
[phonetext* phonetext-118 numberonly]
</label>    
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Subject (required)
    [text subject placeholder "Choose a subject"] </label>
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-4 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Choose a Budget (USD)
    [select menu-18 "1K - 2K" "Less than 5K" "5K - 10K" "Over 10K" "Please advice"]</label> 
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-12 vc_col-sm-12">
<label> Project details
    [textarea message placeholder "Brief project details"] </label> 
</div>
<div class="vc_col-lg-12 vc_col-sm-12">
[submit "Get a Quote"]  
</div>
```

I tried looking through the sendinblue.php and the php files for Country Phone Plugin. I can somewhat understand the latter, however the sendinblue.php file is confusing me as to how it matches the attributes, particularly the sms attribute.

I currently have both the tel field up and the County & Phone field up.

I tried using just the Country Phone Plugin alone and nothing happened. The contact was not created on Brevo.

The normal tel field works, but there's no indication or validation that this number is the valid amount for this country etc.